# Best way to store date and time with MySQL PHP + AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm making a web based project management application using MySQL and PHP that uses JS (Jquery) in the front end. The user has to input a date and optionally time as well.

However I'm not sure how I should go about inserting and storing the date and converting it back to human readable form in the application.

Thanks in advance,
RayQuang

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Always use the standard Date/Time types for the respective situation.

In MySQL, use one of the appropriate [Date and Time Type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-types.html).  Don't just blindly use one type.  If you're storing a date, don't use a timestamp.  If you're storing a timestamp, don't use a date.  Use the proper type and be done.

In PHP, you can use an integer (parse from mysql's type with [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Talking with JS, I'd suggest using [RFC 2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822) date format, since it's standard.  That way, you're communicating externally using a standard date/time format (which is non-ambiguous).

Answer (score 1):

Store as timestamp.timestamp contain both date and time. and it will be best way to store date and time .

Comment: Don't blindly store as a timestamp.  Timestamp is limited (and subject to the y2k38 problem), and exact behavior depends upon the server's state.  If you need a timestamp, use one.  But don't use it blindly over the other (sometimes more appropriate) methods...

Comment: I'm pretty sure the y2k38 problem will solve itself because the limit is based upon the bit depth of the number, which can be increase merely with a newer version.  Y2K was a totally different problem because it was limited by 2 places, and we were about to hit 100 (1900+100).